# Can't access autowired object in Spring converter

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, converters

I am writing a small Spring application that consists of a model represented by a facade object called `service` and a JSP-based view. In between I have the usual Spring controllers and a converter that converts a string id to an object from the model.

This converter uses the service object, which is `@Autowired`, to find the right model object from `service`. The problem is that whenever the converter accesses a method in `service` nothing happens. No errors or exceptions, it just continues and returns null.

I have already checked whether `service` gets properly initialized or not and that doesn't seem to be the problem. While debugging i noticed that the program goes through `ThreadPoolExecutor` and stops there whenever i try to execute a method on `service`. This makes me assume that the problem is related to accessing `service` while it's locked.

I have already tried to place the necessary code in a synchronized block but that doesn't help. Can anyone tell my why I can't access any methods from an `@Autowired` object  in a Spring converter?

Here is the converter class for what it's worth:

```
public class IdToPublisherConverter implements Converter<String, Publisher>{

    @Autowired
    private MainService service;

    @Override
    public Publisher convert(String id) {
        return service.getPublisher(Long.getLong(id));
    }   
}
```

EDIT:

`MainService` is a facade object that provides an interface to get, add, update and remove my model data (`Game` objects and `Publisher`objects)

`service.getPublisher(id)` gets a `Publisher`object from `service` based on an id of type long the converter recieved from a JSP page. This method goes to the following method in `MainService`:

```
@Override
public Publisher getPublisher(long id) {
    Publisher publisher = repository.readPublisher(id);
    return publisher;
}
```

Which goes to:

```
private final Map<Long, Publisher> publishers;

...

@Override
public Publisher readPublisher(long id) {
    return publishers.get(id);
}
```

Comment: What is `MainService`? What does `getPublisher` do? Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: You already state that `service` is initialized (and thus autowiring worked) and identified that the object referenced by `service` is locked. So we need to see what `service.getPublisher(...)` is doing (the code, not a description) in order to tell you why it gets locked etc.

Comment: You're sure the `publishers` map in your repository is not empty?

Comment: @home 
Yes, I'm sure `publishers` is not empty. In fact I'm pretty sure there is no trivial reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: The dependency injection looks good. There seems to be a bug in getPublisher(). Are you really sure if the value exists for that key? Have you tried to debug or log all invocations of readPublisher(long) method to be sure that data is in place and it's been invoked?

Comment: @MartinStrejc 
Again, yes I'm sure the map contains the related value for a given key. I am currently using a test version of `service` that contains some dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

So after an hour of fiddling, I finally located and solved my own problem.
The issue was not related to multithreading but rather to the conversion from String to long. Instead of using `Long.getLong(id)`, I should have used something like this:

```
@Override
public Publisher convert(String idString) {
    return service.getPublisher(Long.parseLong(idString));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add @Component annotation to your converter. Make sure your converter registered in SpringConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class ServerConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry) {
        converterAutoscanner(formatterRegistry);
        super.addFormatters(formatterRegistry);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private void converterAutoscanner(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry)    {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.somepackege");
        Set<Class<? extends Converter>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Converter.class);
        allClasses.forEach(s -> {
            try {
                formatterRegistry.addConverter(s.newInstance());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(e);
            }
        });
    }
}


@Component
public class CommentConverter implements Converter<String, Comment>{
    //converter code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define IdToPublisherConverter as bean. like this

```
@Service
public class IdToPublisherConverter...
```

Only beans initialized can use @Autowired annotation, otherwise you'll get null.
If IdToPublisherConverter is not a bean, user ClasspathXmlApplicationcontext to get spring beans.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your service has @Service annotation, for example

```
@Service("mainService")
public class MainService...
```

and inside it, if you have transactional methods, don't forget @Transactional

With few code shown it's complicated, but I think it helps to you if that's the case.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `@Service`and `@Transactional` annotations do but I don't want to use any Spring-specific stuff in my backend. Maintaining the loose coupling between my view and my model is a high priority for me.

Comment: @Exevan I think those annotations are fine, when I need flexibility between view and model, is important to have many tiers, the class with Service annotation is practically independient of your view and model... with a view using a Backing bean you only need to invoke the service whatever you want, for example, if you want disaggregate a few more, you can also include a Delegate class as a Component (annotation), and invoke your services through it... so your model and your view are going to be more flexible if you need changes